# MySQL Cannot Truncate and Delete all data in partition table

Tags: mysql

As said, I'm doing and practicing a partition data in MySQL.
As I want to clear all the data, the data still there and cannot delete in one time.

This is the partition table that I created.

```
CREATE TABLE events
(
    event_id INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    inserted_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    last_updated_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    data JSON NOT NULL,
    KEY (event_id)
)
default charset utf8 
PARTITION BY RANGE(to_days(inserted_date))
(
PARTITION p20210301 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2021-04-01')),
PARTITION p20210401 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2021-05-01')),
PARTITION p20210501 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2021-06-01')),
PARTITION p20210601 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2021-07-01')),
PARTITION p20210701 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2021-08-01')),
PARTITION p20210801 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2021-09-01')),
PARTITION p20210901 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2021-10-01')),
PARTITION p20211001 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2021-11-01')),
PARTITION p20211101 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2021-12-01')),
PARTITION p20211201 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2022-01-01')),
PARTITION p20220101 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2022-02-01')),
PARTITION p20220201 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2022-03-01')),
PARTITION p20220301 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2022-04-01')),
PARTITION p20220401 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2022-05-01')),
PARTITION p20220501 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2022-06-01')),
PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) 
);
```

First question is everytime I select all data, different rows of data come out.
[image]

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    plover_audit_log.events
```

Second I can't truncate the table. Everytime I truncate the table, the data still there.
[image]

```
truncate table plover_audit_log.events;
```

Third even I try to delete the data, it cannot delete completely. The data still there after delete.
[image]

```
delete from plover_audit_log.events;
```

I'm curious on is my MySQL software problem? Or partition table make this happen?
Because I have a backup table **without partition** is work well with Truncate, Delete and Select script.

Comment: Please publish your truncate and delete statements

Comment: Demonstrate this on the online fiddle (for example, on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 - create table, add data, try to query/truncate/delete...).

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using, it might be relevant

Comment: @P.Salmon I have update the post but also the truncate and delete statement have been show in the picture also

Comment: @RiggsFolly The version of MySQL Server and Workbench are 8.0.23

Comment: have you writing anything Realtime on this table, seems data is generating continuously.

Comment: can you check  output of these queries `select max(inserted_date) from plover_audit_log.events; truncate table plover_audit_log.events;select max(inserted_date) from plover_audit_log.events;`

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA Yes, it should have a .net core project to call this database. But currently, I just practicing on MySQL so there is no other things to do any CRUD function on this database.

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA Well, I have run your script and there still have data after truncate table like ```2031-03-01 00:00:00```

Comment: have you got smae output **(inserted_date)** select statement same both times. Here you are not using default value so better execute `select max(event_id) from plover_audit_log.events;`  before and after truncate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230022/discussion-between-rohit-khurana-and-steven-yu).

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA Nope, different date. Seems like some data have been deleted and truncate table cannot delete data completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data was running by one **procedure**, which found in processlist. So first need to  kill that pid from processlist. like `kill pid;`
then execute truncate and check if data is still persist

Comment: Yes, this guy have solved my problem. Here is how to check the procedure list. ```SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST```

Answer (score 0):

Partitioned tables require a slightly different instruction to perform a TRUNCATE

To remove data from all partitions

```
ALTER plover_audit_log.events TRUNCATE PARTITION ALL;
```

To remove all data from a specific partition

```
ALTER plover_audit_log.events TRUNCATE PARTITION p20210301;
```

> Reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html

Comment: I have solved this as I did a stupid thing. I have a procedure to insert dummy data and this procedure didn't stop at all